# What permissions do I need to run SQL*Loader?

Tags: oracle10g, permissions, oracle

What permissions does a database user need to be able to run oracle's sql loader?  For instance, since sql loader will disable indexes and triggers, does it need ALTER permissions for those items?

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find any documentation on this in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found through experimentation is that the user needs `ALTER` permissions for both the table it's loading into and any triggers.